# How to turn off alignment-indent after line continuation in Shell-script mode?

Tags: indentation, shell-mode

In `Shell-script[sh]` mode, Emacs defaults to this style of indentation:

```
/this/is/an/example/command/broken/over_multiple_lines which \
                                                       causes \
                                                       an \
                                                       annoying \
                                                       indentation
```

I would like to change this so that each line is indented by only a single tab further than the original line:

```
/this/is/another example \
  which is indented \
  by a single tab \
  shown here \
  as two spaces
```

This is what the relevant section of my `init.el` says I have customised:

```
 '(sh-backslash-align t)
 '(sh-basic-offset 2)
 '(sh-indent-after-continuation nil)
 '(sh-indent-for-continuation 0)
 '(sh-indentation 2))
```

What variable am I missing to change the alignment indent to a single-tab indent?

Comment: You seem to be looking for the default behavior. Try bisecting your init file for the faulty setting. For the record, with these values for the 5 variables, I get no indentation at all after the continuation.

Answer (score 3):

Open a file in `shell-script-mode`, run `M-x customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `sh-indent-after-continuation`, and see if you can set it to `always`. (This seems to be a relatively new option, Emacs 25.1+)