# sh-script alignment issues

Tags: indentation, major-mode, shell-mode, bash

I'm sure emacs used to do it my way, but things appear to have changed (probably years ago, I've just been living with the pain).

I want this (to conform to corp. standards):

```
MULTIFORM=$(
    curl -k -A http://foo.com |
    grep -m1 multiform |
    tr '=' '\n' |
    tail -1 |
    cut -d "'" -f 2
)
```

But emacs-25.1 insists that this is the right way to indent:

```
MULTIFORM=$(
    curl -k -A http://foo.com |
        grep -m1 multiform |
        tr '=' '\n' |
        tail -1 |
        cut -d "'" -f 2
         )
```

... quite apart from our standards, it's ugly.

I've tried messing around with sh-learn-line-indent and it offers rules like:

```
close-all ")"
list-intro ";"
```

... but playing with them gives no joy at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like being worth a bug-report.

Comment: You can see if the settings from this question (not the answer): http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/26329/184 help.

Comment: I did read that one but it appears to be another version of emacs??? Anyway, mine doesn't have variables sh-indentation-*. And I have tried yr suggestion of moving aside .emacs .elisp.d and .config/emacs. Nothing seems to make any difference. How does other people emacs' treat the above?

Comment: ... and I'll enter a bug report if I get nowhere with this - good suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the indentation after the `|` you should be able to get the right result by going to the incorrect line (i.e. the one that starts with `grep`) and then do `M-x smie-config-set-indent RET before "|" RET nil RET`.

But smie-config is not up to the task when it comes to tweaking the behavior of the close paren in the way you want.  For that you'll need actual code.  One possible approach could look like:

```
(defun my-sh-indent-rules ()
  (when (eq ?= (char-before))
    (skip-chars-backward "[:alnum:]_=")
    (current-column)))

(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'smie-indent-functions
                      #'my-sh-indent-rules
                      nil 'local)))
```

BTW, if you want to handle the `|` alignment "by hand" rather than via `smie-config`, you could do it this way:

```
(defun my-sh-smie-rules (orig-fun kind token)
  (pcase (cons kind token)
   (`(:before . "|") nil)
   (_ (funcall orig-fun kind token))))
(advice-add 'sh-smie-sh-rules :around #'my-sh-smie-rules)
```

wef: This is the final bit of the puzzle that Stefan gave me in my muddle below - how to save the customisations for next time. As he said, I needed to teach `smie` about my preferences eg with `M-x smie-config-set-indent` then run `M-x smie-config-save` and look at the variable `smie-config`. Finally, I copied those rules (in my case, just one rule) into `.emacs`:

```
(defun my-sh-indent-rules ()
  (smie-config-local '((nil :before "|" (column . 8)))))
(add-hook 'smie-indent-functions #'my-sh-indent-rules)
```

There may be other ways to do this eg with the commands in `sh-mode` eg `M-x sh-learn-line-indent` - but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: Hmmm - M-x smie-config-set-indent gave me choices for `Adjust rule:` of:
`after ";"` and `before ";"` but it objected to: `before "|"` with `"No match"`

Comment: my-sh-indent-rules appears to work!! Thank you for that. I tried upvoting the answer but I don't have reputation for that.

Comment: `M-x smie-config-show-indent` on the 'grep' line shows:

    Rules used:  : before "|" -> (column . 8), :elem basic -> 4, :after "|" -> nil

Comment: The output you give for `smie-config-show-indent` looks right, so you just need to `M-x smie-config-set-indent` at the same place and set `before "|"` to `nil`.

Comment: Hoo boy! that worked like a bought one! Thanks so much! Now I need to try and work out why I missed that - I thought I'd tried all the combinations and permutations. Obviously not!

Comment: I want to put it all in my .emacs but having some problems. So I set up as above and ran `M-x smie-save-config`. `smie-config` says that its value is ((sh-mode (nil :before "|" (column . 8))))

So I tried this:

(defun my-sh-indent-rules ()
  ((sh-mode (nil :before "|" (column . 8)))))

(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook 'my-sh-indent-rules)

Obviously, that doesn't work.

Comment: `smie-config-save` does write to your `~/.emacs`, so there's nothing more to do to "put it all in my .emacs".  If you want to do it in your mode hook, then add `(smie-config-local '((nil :before "|" (column . 8))))` in there.

Comment: Sorry to be such an elisp ingénue, but I stuck this in .emacs and now it formats all lines with zero indent!  
(defun my-sh-indent-rules ()
  (smie-config-local '((nil :before "|" (column . 8)))))
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook #'my-sh-indent-rules)

Comment: ... and, on my emacs-25.1, `smie-config-save` does not save to .emacs (I tried it with emacs -Q) - it saves to a variable `smie-config`. It's on fedora-24 emacs-25.1-0.2.rc1.fc24.x86_64

Comment: Duh! I finally got everything lined up - I needed this: 
(defun my-sh-indent-rules ()
  (smie-config-local '((nil :before "|" (column . 8)))))
(add-hook 'smie-indent-functions #'my-sh-indent-rules)
 Sorry for the bacndwidth.

Comment: I feel I should document this somewhere - perhaps I'll just tidy everything up and add it to your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Indeed `smie-config-save` "saves" to `smie-config`, but `smie-config` is then saved by `customize` (via `customize-save-customized` or somesuch).  I guess it should ask the user whether to save into `~/.emacs` and call `customize` itself accordingly.  Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` asking for this.  As for editing my answer, please be my guest, yes.

Comment: BTW - the '(pcase' line above should read '(pcase (cons kind token)'

Comment: my 'Duh!' cos I forgot to update this entry 2 years ago! Pressure of work.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a broken (or incomplete) answer ...  I'm trying to fix my original problem using the `sh-mode` calls only instead of the lower-level `smie` calls that Stefan was kind enough to provide, just to see if it can be done. Reading those docs and running in a fresh `emacs -Q` session, I did this:

```
M-x sh-learn-line-indent RET before "|" RET nil
```

The style then worked for me and indented the lines ending in "|" - but not the final ")" - I'll still need Stefan's code for that. Then:

```
M-x sh-name-style RET bobs
M-x sh-save-styles-to-buffer RET *scratch*
```

and then used that code to create this:

```
(defun my-sh-indent-rules ()
  (setq sh-styles-alist
        '(("bobs"
           (sh-basic-offset . 4)
           (sh-first-lines-indent . 0)
           (sh-indent-after-case . +)
           (sh-indent-after-do . +)
           (sh-indent-after-done . 0)
           (sh-indent-after-else . +)
           (sh-indent-after-if . +)
           (sh-indent-after-loop-construct . +)
           (sh-indent-after-open . +)
           (sh-indent-comment . t)
           (sh-indent-for-case-alt . ++)
           (sh-indent-for-case-label . +)
           (sh-indent-for-continuation . +)
           (sh-indent-for-do . 0)
           (sh-indent-for-done . 0)
           (sh-indent-for-else . 0)
           (sh-indent-for-fi . 0)
           (sh-indent-for-then . 0))))
  (sh-load-style "bobs"))
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook #'my-sh-indent-rules)
```

... note that it has no `before "|"` rule. Perhaps it doesn't know how to do that?

Anyway, running that in a fresh `emacs -Q` session it doesn't work even after a `M-x sh-load-style RET bobs`, so I'm reverting to the default behaviour.

I'm happy with Stefan's `smie` solution above, but I'd be interested to know how to make it work with `sh-mode`.

Comment: I think `sh-styles-*` stuff only works if you set `sh-use-smie` to `nil`.

Comment: @npostavs - you're right, it works now, at least for indenting the pipeline. It may need more work to get the ')' to indent correctly.